# Undefined function or method 'shuffle' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: oop, matlab

I am trying to create a class 'Deck' that has methods shuffle and deal, however, I do         not know why my function for 'shuffle' isn't running. I get the error message :

> Undefined function or method 'shuffle' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Can someone please explain why the function is not running? thank you very much.
I am calling upon a previously created classdef 'Card'

```
 classdef Deck < handle;
 properties;
     diamond;
     spade
     heart;
     club;


    end;
     methods;
       function obj=create(deck);
         for k=1:13;
             %Designate a number to each suit to create the deck
             obj(k).diamond=cards('D','R',k);
             obj(k).spade=cards('S','B',k);
             obj(k).heart=cards('H','R',k);
            obj(k).club=cards('C','B',k);
         end
         %Create a vector of each suit and number accordingly until we
         %have 52 cards. 13 of each suit.
         obj={obj.diamond obj.spade obj.heart obj.club};            

     end

     %%
     function obj=shuffle(obj);

             shuff=randperm(52);

         for k=1:52;  
             hf=shuff(k);
             obj(k)=obj(hf);


         end
         end

     end
   end
```

Comment: aha oh ya, I guess I forgot that. Thank you.

Comment: What does this line do: obj{k}=obj(hf); If this code is a matlab code, I think that the curly braces don't come on the left side of the '=' sign. They are used only for assigning values on the left side. Also what is shuffl function in line: hf=shuff(k);?

Comment: I did the obj(k)=obj(hf) to scramble the order of it's index thus shuffling the cards. ya, i dont' know about the curly braces. I thought to use them since the deck is a cell, but mainly that line is to shuffle the order of the deck.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the last line in the constructor:

```
obj = { obj.diamond obj.spade obj.heart obj.club }
```

This line turns your object into a cell (?). Try remove this line.
Try this `classdef` instead

```
classdef Deck 
     properties 
          cards
     end
 methods
     function obj = Deck()
          % do your stuff here, but no obj. before diamond/spade/heart/club
          obj.cards = { diamond, spade, heart, club };
     end 
     function obj  =shuffle ( obj )
          obj.cards = obj.cards( randperm(52) );
     end
 end
```

Comment: I used that line in order to create a vector of 52 entries. I have just tried removing it, but then I get only structure of 13 1x1 structure each containing diamond,spade,club,heart. This is what I got a=create(deck)

a = 

1x13 struct array with fields:
    diamond
    spade
    heart
    club
a = 

1x13 struct array with fields:
    diamond
    spade
    heart
    club

EDU>> a(1)

ans = 

    diamond: [1x1 cards]
      spade: [1x1 cards]
      heart: [1x1 cards]
       club: [1x1 cards]

Comment: @larryquach in that case you need your properties to be not the 4 "shapes" but a single cell, let's say `deck` and then you'll have to change the class accordingly.

Comment: So tried this but I get an error that says Maximum recursion limit 500 reached.
This is my current code : classdef Deck < handle;
     properties 
          card;
     end
 methods
     function obj = Deck();
         for k=1:13;
             diamond=cards('D','R',k);
             spade=cards('S','B',k);
             heart=cards('H','R',k);
             club=cards('C','B',k);
         obj(k).card = { diamond, spade, heart, club };
         end
         
     end
         function obj  =shuffle ( obj )
          obj.card = obj.card( randperm(52) );
     end
 end
 end

Comment: You cannot have `obj(k)` in the constructor - you construct a **single** object. You might have `obj.card(k) = { ... } ;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have a property which is an array of `Card` objects. See the [MATLAB documentation for object arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-arrays.html). Here's how I would solve this problem:

```
classdef Deck < handle
    properties
        % This will be an object array of Card objects.
        CardArray
    end

    properties (Dependent)
        nCards
    end

    methods 
        function This = Deck()
            % preallocate arrays.
            % the constructor for Card should accept 0 arguments.
            Diamond(13) = Card('D', 'R', 13);
            Spade(13) = Card('S', 'B', 13);
            Heart(13) = Card('H', 'R', 13);
            Club(13) = Card('C', 'B', 13);

            % now fill in the rest of each suit
            for iVal = 1:12
                Diamond(iVal) = Card('D', 'R', iVal);
                Spade(iVal) = Card('S', 'B', iVal); 
                Heart(iVal) = Card('H', 'R', iVal); 
                Club(iVal) = Card('C', 'B', iVal);  
            end

            % finally concatenate them into a single array
            This.CardArray = [Diamond, Spade, Heart, Club];
        end

        function shuffle(This) 
            This.CardArray = This.CardArray(randperm(This.nCards)); 
        end

        function n = get.nCards(This)
            n = length(This.CardArray);
        end
    end
end
```

You need to make sure that your `Card` constructor accepts zero arguments. For example, you could do the following:

```
classdef Card < handle

    properties
        symbol = 'D'
        color = 'R'
        value = 1;
    end

    methods
        function This = Card(varargin)
            if nargin >= 1
                This.symbol = varargin{1};
            end
            if nargin >= 2
                This.color = varargin{2};
            end
            if nargin >= 3
                This.value = varargin{3};
            end
        end

    end

end
```